# Google map API key on different android devices

Tags: android, android-mapview, api-key

I'm using MapView in my app. I have API key from google fore my release key store.

I'exporting signed APK with eclipse and trying to install it on devices.

On G1 device with Android 1.6 everything works well, but on HTC Desire with android 2.2 maps doesn't appear. I see just grey grid and zoom controls.

Where problem can be?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with your Maps API key. I think it has to do with differences in the Google APIs from version 1.6 and 2.2. Do you get any errors in your logcat or just an empty map?

Comment: I'm installing signed APK through cmd or through terminal, so i really don'tknow how to watch logcat. When i'm installing my app with eclipse - map works correctly. And on 2.2 simulator it works too